# React - New props mapped to children return undefined from within a Higher Order Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a HOC that injects API routes into my components so I do not need to define them every-time I want to make a fetch request within a parent component. Currently the props mapped into the children are `undefined` when called. Here is my attempt so far:

The file I am eventually passing as props through the HOC:

```
import { blog_routes } from '../api/blog/blog';
import { fetch_config } from './fetch_config/fetch_config';

export const routes = {
  fetch_config,
  blog: blog_routes
};
```

The Higher Order Component `InjectApiRoutes`:

```
    import React from 'react';
    const api = require('../../api/index');

    const GlobalApiRoutes = Component => {
      return class InjectApiRoutes extends React.Component {
        render() {
          return <Component api={api.routes} {...this.props} />;
        }
      };
    };

export default GlobalApiRoutes;
```

I have a `Page` component that is a layout component. In this case, The `Page` Parent component is used within `Blog` to setup `Blog` with the default `Page` layout.

Here is `Page` note that is wrapped with the `GlobalApiRoutes` HOC:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

//HoC
import GlobalApiRoutes from '../Hoc/InjectApiRoutes';

//Styling
import { PageContainer, PageTitle, ChildrenContainer } from './styles';

const Page = props => {
  const { children, pageTitle } = props;

  const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(children, child =>
    React.cloneElement(child, { api: props.api })
  );

  return (
    <PageContainer>
      <PageTitle>
        <h2>{pageTitle}</h2>
      </PageTitle>
      <ChildrenContainer>{childrenWithProps}</ChildrenContainer>
    </PageContainer>
  );
};

export default GlobalApiRoutes(Page);

Page.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  pageName: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

And here is the `Blog` component that is using `Page`:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import Page from '../../Layout/Page';

const Blog = props => {
  console.log(props.api);
  return (
    <Page pageTitle="Blog">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </Page>
  );
};

export default Blog;
```

My issue with this is that in my `Blog` component, I do not have the `api` prop that was added in `Page`. It comes back as `undefined`.

I know I am missing something here, but I can not figure out what that is. Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: The pattern you have shown **could be argued to be** what `context` is used for - you have a component several layers up in a tree and you want a child to access some stuff.

Comment: You also haven't shown where you're rendering Blog - it needs to be an immediately child of `Page`. To be honest, it looks like this is a really overcomplicated setup. They are static routes, just import them where you need them. Get rid of this HOC stuff.

Comment: Wait a second, `Blog` is a `parent` of page? Page has essentially added those api props to your `h1` element. It looks like what you really wanted to do is `GlobalApiRoutes(Blog)` and not `GlobalApiRoutes(Page)`

Comment: @Adam that’s right, it should be wrapped around Blog and not Page. I guess my wording is not the greatest. Page is just a layout component that sets up the default page layout. Blog is using Page internally, so yes, Blog would be the parent in this case. I confused myself here thinking that Page was the parent. thanks for your comments!